# length in "string" vs length in new String("string")

Tags: javascript

Why does:

```
var a = "string";
console.log("length" in a);
```

Gives error

```
var b = new String("string");
console.log("length" in b);
```

Gives true.

a has property length just as same as b. a typeof is string but it's also an object with its own properties. MDN says:

> JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects , so that it's possible to use String object methods for primitive strings.

What's wrong?

Comment: "*a typeof is string but it's also an object with it's own properties.*" - well no.

Comment: The implicit context is omitted in your quote: "JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects *[when accessing properties]*". The `in` operator does not access a property.

Answer (score 1):

The `in` keyword works only on objects.

```
var a = 'foo';
var b = new String(a);

console.log(typeof a);  // "string"
console.log(typeof b);  // "object"
```

Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) on the distinction between string primitives and string objects

The following code will automatically convert the primitive to an object upon accessing a property, in this case `length`.

```
console.log("string".length);
```

Answer (score 0):

**b** is an object of type **String**, while **a** is not, it is a **string**.
If you try `a.isPrototypeOf(String)` it should output `false`